# Symfony form rendering with custom labels and collections

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony

While trying to get used to symfony3 forms I have a problem with customizing the view of a form.

I´m trying to build a form to bet on football games like

team1Name (logoTeam1) [1] : [2] (logoTeam2) team2Name

team3Name (logoTeam3) [2] : [0] (logoTeam4) team4Name
...

Very simple I thought but not with symfonies form builder (or maybe I just dont get it).

I read through (I think) all the documentation but didnt found a clean solution yet. I think it would be possible by using a custom array form, but this seems dirty.

So I tried to bring my classes to fit in symfonies form logic.

Used Classes:

**gamebet** : consists of betteam1 Integer, betteam2 Integer, a game object and some other stuff and is connected with a game via doctrine

https://github.com/Invis00/pub/blob/master/Gamebet.php

**game** : has the game information like Team1Name, Team2Name and so on

https://github.com/Invis00/pub/blob/master/Game.php

**gamebetCollection** : a class I created to hold a collection of gamebet objects since every row in my form is a gamebet object and so I'm able to use smyfonies Collection Type.

**Custom GamebetType**

```
class GamebetType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder->add('betteam1', IntegerType::class);
      $builder->add('betteam2', IntegerType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Gamebet',
    ));
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
(...)
$formbuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($userBets);
$form = $formbuilder
     ->add('gamebets', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => GamebetType::class,
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'required'  => false,
                'attr'      => array('gamebets' => $userBets)
        )))
        ->add('bet', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Tippen'))
        ->getForm();
 (...)
```

**Template**

```
            {{ form_start(form) }}
             <table>

             {% for gamebet in form.gamebets %}
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ form_label(gamebet.betteam1) }}</td>
                     <td><img src=pic/</td>
                     <td>{{ form_row(gamebet.betteam1) }}</td>
                     <td> : </td>
                     <td>{{ form_row(gamebet.betteam2) }}</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>{{ form_label(gamebet.betteam2) }}</td>
                 </tr>
             {% endfor %}

             </table>
             {{ form_end(form) }}
```

After some searching I was at least able to build the form and create one row for each gamebet although it seems not "clean" to me.

My problem:
How is it possible to customize the labels for each object of the collection so that I can render the teamnames? At the moment I've absolutely no idea how to pass and get the data of the single objecte of the collection.

Is it possible to access it in the custom Type (I tried to pass it via the array but have no idea how to get the "current" object).

Is it possible to access it in the template since I would need it not just for the lable but also for creating the Logos URL.

Is there a way to access those information because at the moment I really have no idea how to solve this simple form problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do, you don't need a gamebetCollection class.

Instead you should create a parent form with the collectionType and 'data_class' => null.

You can use the symfony cookbook documentation :
 http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
Or 
 [One form with all row of one entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003014/one-form-with-all-row-of-one-entity)

Update:

In your Twig you could do something like that :

```
     {% for for gamebet in form.gamebets %}
                        {{ form_errors(gamebet) }}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ form_label(gamebet.betteam1) }}</td>
                            <td><img src=pic/{{ gamebet.vars.value.betteam1 }}.jpg</td>
                            <td>{{ form_widget(gamebet.betteam1, {'attr': {'class': 'c-select'}}) }}</td>
                           ...
                        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think the solution there is basically the same isnt it? There is a Task with a collection of Tags (I have a GamebetCollection with a collection of Gamebets)

This is working for me, but what I would need is the possiblity to set the label for each element within the collection. 

Translated to the example you posted:
In the example there is a collection of tags and what I would do is to set the label for each tag in the collection (every tag has a different label)

And I also would need the possiblity to access attributes of these tags in the template to create a pic element for each tag.

Comment: Already tried that, the problem I have is, that I'm still not able to customize the label for each gamebet.betteam1 and gamebet.betteam2 Form element.

I'm able to show the label in the template but not to set the label to i.e. gamebet.betteam1.game.team1.name and so on

Comment: Why dont you have a team entity linked with your gamebet1 and gamebet2 ?
Actually where the link between the gamebet1 and the name of the team ?

Comment: I have. My gamebet has an object game which has two object team1 and team2 mapped via doctrine. I am able to get the information from a gamebet object.

But I have no idea how to get this information to the label.

Comment: The classes if they are of interest:
https://github.com/Invis00/pub/blob/master/Gamebet.php
https://github.com/Invis00/pub/blob/master/Game.php

Comment: Do you try <td>{{ gamebet.game.team1.name) }}</td> ? 
You can try a {% dump(gamebet)} %} in your loop to check

Comment: dump solved it!
In gamebet.vars.data the coresponding object for the form ist stored. So from there it is possible to get all the information i need:
gamebet.vars.data.game.team1.getNamelong

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dump solved it! In gamebet.vars.data the coresponding object for the form ist stored. So from there it is possible to get all the information i need: gamebet.vars.data.game.team1.getNamelong Thanks!