# Symfony2 create a form type to add multiple records of the same type

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony

I need to create a form type that will create multiple records of a certain Entity.

I figured out to create a parent Form Type and then add a collection inside. This parent Type isn't bind to any entity, but child Type is. The problem is, that when I process the request, I get an empty data object.

Here is my parent Type:

```
class ChallengeCollectionType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email_invitations', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EmailInvitationType::class
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

}
```

My Child Type:

```
class EmailInvitationType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', EmailType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'        => Challenge::class,
            'csrf_protection'   => false
        ));
    }

}
```

Here is how I process my data in Controller:

```
public function inviteEmailAction(Request $request){

        $form = $this->createForm(ChallengeCollectionType::class);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        dump($form->getData());
        dump($form->get('email_invitations')->getData());
        die();
}
```

I submit data in a POST request (this is API and there's no HTML form) like this:

```
challenge_collection[email_invitations][0][email] = "email@address.com"
challenge_collection[email_invitations][1][email] = "address@email.com"
```

And Controller returns empty [] for all dumps.

I've actually found a workaround, but it looks bad:

```
        $data = ['email_invitations' => [new Challenge(), new Challenge()]];        

        $form = $this->createForm(ChallengeCollectionType::class, $data);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

And this will work, so I have to send an array of empty objects of the type of the Entity to get request processed.

Or even this way:

```
    $data = ['email_invitations' => []];

    if(!empty($request->request->get('challenge_collection'))){
        if(!empty($request->request->get('challenge_collection')['email_invitations'])){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($request->request->get('challenge_collection')['email_invitations']); $i ++){
                $data['email_invitations'][] = new Challenge();
            }
        }
    }
```

There should be a better way to do it, please help me to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `allow_add` and `allow_delete` options in collection field type. [See the Collection field type documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

Also, this is important for parent entity to have an `mapped-by` association with child entity, which would get you child objects in an `ArrayCollection` object in controller.

Further, if you want to save/remove them automatically as per the request, you need to implement a 'by_reference`false and set association with`cascade-persist`and`cascade-remove`.

I have used `collection` field type with API numerous times, and it worked like charm. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try in your controller something like :

```
$invitations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('yourInvitationEntityClass')->findAll());         
$form = $this->createForm(ChallengeCollectionType::class, $invitations );
```

You could find explanations here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

[One form with all row of one entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003014/one-form-with-all-row-of-one-entity)

Comment: Thank you for reply! My concern is, that the findAll() in this case can return thousands of records, is it a good way to run a heavy request to the database to get some data that I will not actually use? In this case my cycle to create a set of empty entities looks more efficient

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Mikhaylovskiy the findAll() was just an example. you can make your own request in your repository and use it. but if it's just to create new effectively thats not a good way to do it :c). In this case you should try  to use Prototype : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Comment: As I understand, Prototype is used only for the front end, but I'm not concerned about it because I'm building API. In the example with the tags there is getTags(), that returns all tags related to the entity. But I don't have an entity in my case.