# Embedding a collection of forms. Empty results

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I'm following the question and answer here:
[One form with all row of one entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003014/one-form-with-all-row-of-one-entity)

My files are:

PermissionCollectionType:

```
class PermissionsCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('permissions', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => PermissionsContentsType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null
        ));
    }
}
```

PermissionsContentsType:

```
class PermissionsContentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Name',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Name'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('view', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('new', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('edit', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('delete', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('accept', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'label' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Categories::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function permissionsAction(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, $role, $type, UserInterface $user)
{
    $categoriesRepository = $em->getRepository('App:Categories');
    $list = $categoriesRepository->findAll();

    $form = $this->createForm(PermissionsCollectionType::class, $list);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('Acl\permissionForm.html.twig', [
        'list' => $list,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

{{ form(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, the form displays only a word 'Permissions' and nothing more, like the list doesn't exist. What could be the issue or how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `PermissionCollectionType` will look into your `$list` array to find the `permissions` key, which doesn't exist. To fix, try setting the key before giving it to the form (as is done in your linked question+answer):

```
//...
$list = array('permissions' => $list);
$form = $this->createForm(PermissionsCollectionType::class, $list);
//...
```